# Overcoming 'max_user_connections' issue with polling/comet/websockets

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, websocket

I have a php/mysql auction site which uses a while/break loop to check on the current active item in a items table using ajax polling. It breaks if there is a new bid or a new lot. The server script is:

```
if ($action == "ping"){
    $idle_lot = $_POST['lot'];
    $idle_bid = $_POST['bid'];
    $timeout = 15;
    $now = time();
    while((time() - $now) < $timeout) {
        $get_bid_status = $db->prepare("SELECT current_bid, lot_number FROM ".$lots_table." WHERE lot_status='active' LIMIT 1");
        $get_bid_status->execute(array());
        $existCount = $get_bid_status->rowCount();
        if ($existCount > 0 ) {             
            while($row = $get_bid_status->fetch()) {
                $current_bid = $row["current_bid"];
                $lot_number = $row["lot_number"];
            }
            if (($current_bid != $idle_bid)||($idle_lot != $lot_number)) break;             
            sleep(1);               
        } else {
            $return_array[99] = "closed";
        }
        if ($existCount == 0 ) break;
    }
    //other php code here
}
```

The client side is a simple AJAX function:

```
function waitForMsg(lot, bid){       
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "live_bidding_script.php",
    data: { action: "ping", lot: lot, bid: bid},
    dataType: "json",
    async: true, 
    cache: false,
    timeout:50000, 
    success: function(data){                 
         //other jquery code here
         setTimeout(function(){waitForMsg(lot, bid)}, 1000);
        }

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //other jquery code here
        setTimeout(function(){waitForMsg(lot, bid)}, 1000); 
    }
});};
```

The script was working very well in testing, but when we had a simulated auction, we suddenly crashed and burned. We got the dreaded:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1226] User 'XXXX' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)
```

I removed the loop, which seemed to be the major cause of the problem, (ie kept the connection open for 15secs at a time, and quickly used up all the 20 connections) and reverted back to simple polling.

Now from reading dozens of articles, polling and even long polling is not the 'way to go' so to speak. So I am about to recode the site.

My question is out of the newest technologies which use websockets (ie: pub nub, node.js, socket.io or even Comet) would they get around this issue of 'max_server_connections', and if so please explain how/why.

I understand the newer technologies work differently but they all seem to have a fallback approach (usually polling) if WS protocols are not available, which leads me to believe if we had 1000 concurrent users and 20+ had older browsers for example, we would still get the same 'max_server_connections' issue.

PS: we are on a prepaid hosted server for the next few years and simply increasing the number of 'max_user_connections' is a no go. Changing hosts may be an option, albeit a very expensive/time consuming exercise.

Thanks.

Comment: Without getting into the deep technical dive here, there is no doubt PubNub will make your life much easier and your service scalable and very affordable. And the max_connections issue can be easily avoided.

It would seem that your 15 second interval is not "long polling" but rather just "polling". PubNub will abstract the realtime protocol out of your implementation with simple pub/sub API and will allow you to just write your biz logic. And you will be able to listen to thousands of "channels" (auctions, perhaps) with a single connection.

Please contact support@pubnub.com

Comment: And just wanted to address the other options you listed: node.js, socket.io, Comet. None of these address the scalability issue. You would still be writing a ton of code that PubNub has already implemented for you. And you would need to have someone (some team) maintain the operations of keeping this system scalable - PubNub does that for you (runs the server side operations).

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-vs-buy-why-diy-isnt-always-better/ 
http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/229/build-vs-buy

Comment: And about your use case: http://www.pubnub.com/use-cases/realtime-auction-and-price-updates/

Comment: Thanks for the info, i will have a good look at the links you have provided.